# IQueryable<decimal> to decimal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model class which contains a property ProductPrice of type decimal. I am not able to store an IQueryable type to a property decimal. I have even tried to Convert.ToDecimal but it still showing me the error.

**Model - Product**

```
public class Product
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public decimal ProductPrice { get; set; }
    public int ProductQty { get; set; }
}
```

**Model CartDispay**

```
public class CartDisplay
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public String ProductName { get; set; }
    public int ProductQty { get; set; }
    public decimal ProductPrice { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        int userId = 3;
        var items = _context.Cart.Join(_context.Items, c => c.CartId, i => i.CartId, (c, i) => new { c, i }).Where(c => c.c.UserId == userId).ToList();
        foreach(var item in items)
        {
            CartDisplay display = new CartDisplay();
            display.ItemId = item.i.ItemId;
            display.ProductName = _context.Product.Where(p => p.ProductId == item.i.ProductId).Select(p => p.ProductName).ToString();
            display.ProductPrice = _context.Product.Where(p => p.ProductId == item.i.ProductId).Select(p => p.ProductPrice); ;
            display.ProductQty = item.i.ProductQty;
            cartView.CartDisplay.Add(display);
        }
        retu
```

Comment: Why would you expect to be able to store an `IQueryable<decimal>` into a `decimal`? One describes a query, one describes an actual value. Perhaps you'd want to add `.FirstOrDefault()` at the end of your query, but that entirely depends on your business logic.

Comment: FirstOrDefault instead of Where..

Comment: _context.Product.Where(p => p.ProductId == item.i.ProductId).Select(p => p.ProductPrice);  this might return multiple records and since your model CartDisplay has only ProductPrice (not collection) you might get this error. You can use FirstOrDefault() that gives first value from the returned collection. or you can change your model structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IQueryable<T>` defines a sequence of elements of type `T`, rather than a single item. It also lets you perform additional querying without bringing the sequence into memory, but that is not important in the context of your question.

Your situation is a lot simpler, though: rather than querying for individual properties, you should query for the whole product by its ID, then take its individual properties, like this:

```
var prod = _context.Product.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ProductId == item.i.ProductId);
if (prod != null) {
    display.ProductName = prod.ProductName
    display.ProductPrice = prod.ProductPrice;
    display.ProductQty = ...
} else {
    // Product with id of item.i.ProductId does not exist
}
```